# Hue/Hive how to get result from multiple Select query

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

I am using Hue4 for Hive and would like to run several Select statements at the same time, similar to SQL Server Management Studio. I would prefer not to run time-consuming queries one by one to see the final result

```
select 1; #real case : a time-consuming select
select 2; #real case : a time-consuming select
select 3; #real case : a time-consuming select
```

When I run all three at the same time (Ctrl+Enter). I only get result displayed of one. More strangely, every time I run, Hue will decide choose a different result of above three to display (sometimes 1, 2 or 3). There is a small indicator *Showing result of statement #1* near the run button, but I cannot scroll through to access others. Any advices ?

Comment: Why not open Hue in multiple tabs?

Comment: I don't think it's a feasible solution. 1. How many tabs are you going to open if you have a bunch of Select ? 2. Copy each Select on each tab ? I prefer to hold all the script in one file. 3. Hue seems to base on your current session. If you open another tab it will resume the current process on another tab. Changing in one tab cancel the others

Comment: Could you please post your query here?

Comment: The query would be any select as example. There would be no relation between them and I am not looking to bind all results into one table